# Using Multiple JavaScript Onload Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have 2 Onload functions on my website for 2 specific users. However when I add the second OnLoad function, the radio buttons become disabled and I am unable to use them, any ideas why this is?

```
 $(window).on('load', function () {
      if (frmUser.User.value != 'SYSTEM') {
            frmUser.textCustomer.style.backgroundColor = '#cccccc';
            frmUser.textCustomer.disabled = true;
            frmUser.textSiteCode.style.backgroundColor = '#cccccc';
            frmUser.textSiteCode.disabled = true;
            frmUser.option.disabled = true;
            frmUser.radioadd.disabled = true;
            frmUser.radiodelete.disabled = true;
        }
            });

 $(window).on('load', function () {
      if (frmUser.User.value != 'TRAINER') {
            frmUser.textCustomer.style.backgroundColor = '#cccccc';
            frmUser.textCustomer.disabled = true;
            frmUser.textSiteCode.style.backgroundColor = '#cccccc';
            frmUser.textSiteCode.disabled = true;
            frmUser.option.disabled = true;
            frmUser.radioadd.disabled = true;
            frmUser.radiodelete.disabled = true;
        }
            });
```

Here is the code for the rest of the page

```
<asp:Literal ID="litLoginActionHidden" runat="server" />

<div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="height: 21px">
    <asp:Literal ID="errormsg" runat="server"/>
   </td>
   </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<form id="frmUser" method="post" action="/Stock/UserMaint?action=update">
   <div class="screentitle">
     <asp:Literal ID="screentitle" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <table>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="linkBack" Text=" Back" runat="server" ToolTip="Back" class="ApplicationDefault"  ><img class="ApplicationDefault" alt="Back" src="../../Images/external.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
     </td>
     <td>
     </td>
     <td>
        <asp:image ID="Image1"  runat="server" src="../../Images/save.png" ToolTip="Save" onclick="return SubmitForm()" />
     </td>
     <td style="width: 99%; text-align: right">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="linkBackToMainPage" ToolTip="Log Out" runat="server" class="ApplicationDefault" ><img class="ApplicationDefault" alt="Log out" src="../../Images/door_out.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
<div class='FixedDiv' style="text-align: center; height: 179px;" >
 <asp:HyperLink ID="linkLogin" 
                    Text=" " runat="server" />
    <table cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="0px" style="text-align: center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" >
      <!-- row 1 -->  
      <tr class='FixedDiv'>

      <td style="width: 65%; height: 124px;"> <!-- left box -->
        <table>
          <tr class='FixedDiv'>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 15px;"></td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px;">
                <input id="radioupdate" type="radio" name="option" value="Update" onselect="setUpdateActive()" onclick="setUpdateActive()" checked="checked" />  Update</td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px;">
                <input id="radioadd" type="radio" name="option" value="Add" onselect="setAddActive()" onclick="setAddActive()" />  Add</td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px;">
                <input id="radiodelete" type="radio" name="option" value="Add" onselect="setDeleteActive()" onclick="setDeleteActive()" />  Delete</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 15px;"></td>
          </tr>
         <tr class='FixedDiv'>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px;">
                User:</td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px;">
                <asp:Literal id="litUserMaint" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 15px;"></td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px;">
                New User:</td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px;">
              <input disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: #cccccc; width: 151px; height: 15px;" type="text" id="textNewUser" name="textNewUser" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class='FixedDiv'>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px">
                Password:
            </td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px">
                <asp:Literal id="litUserPwd1" runat="server" />
               </td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 15px;"></td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px">
                Confirm Password:
            </td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 15px">
                <asp:Literal id="litUserPwd2" runat="server" />
            </td>
           </tr>
            <tr class='FixedDiv'>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 23px">
                Country:
            </td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 23px">
              <asp:Literal id="litCountryList" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 23px;"></td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 23px">
                Email Address:</td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 23px">
                <asp:Literal id="textEmail" runat="server" />&nbsp;
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 23px">
                Customer Code:
                </td>
                 <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 23px">
              <asp:Literal id="litCustomerCode" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 23px">
                SiteCode:
                </td>
                <td align = 'left' style="width: 20%; height: 23px">
                <asp:Literal id="litSiteCode" runat="server" />
                </td>



                </tr>


                </table>
        </td> 
        </tr>
    <!-- row 1 -->
    </table>
</div>  
</form>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: So changes are the if condition in the second one is true then ?

Comment: If it *is* equal to "SYSTEM", then it will *not* be equal to "TRAINER". It can't be both.

Comment: I had previously used if (frmUser.User.value != 'SYSTEM' || 'TRAINER') {

but that didn't work either

Comment: Why do you want two onload functions? Window gets loaded only once. Two onload handlers is just dirty.

Comment: is there another way to work around this then @JeremyThille

Comment: Just use one onload function... There's no _workaround_. Use one, that's all. If you use 27 "onload" functions, all 27 of them will be triggered on load, so what's the point? Group everything in one. Other programmers looking at your code won't guess there are 26 other onload functions elsewhere, because load event happens only once. So maintenance will be a nightmare. One event, one listener, one onload handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (frmUser.User.value != 'SYSTEM' || frmUser.User.value != 'TRAINER') {
            frmUser.textCustomer.style.backgroundColor = '#cccccc';
            frmUser.textCustomer.disabled = true;
            frmUser.textSiteCode.style.backgroundColor = '#cccccc';
            frmUser.textSiteCode.disabled = true;
            frmUser.option.disabled = true;
            frmUser.radioadd.disabled = true;
            frmUser.radiodelete.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: `if (frmUser.User.value != 'SYSTEM' || 'TRAINER')` is not correct syntax, `if (frmUser.User.value != 'SYSTEM' || frmUser.User.value != 'TRAINER')` is!

Comment: if (frmUser.User.value != 'SYSTEM' || frmUser.User.value != 'TRAINER') does not work either

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(window).on('load', function () {
       if (frmUser.User.value != 'SYSTEM' && !'TRAINER' || frmUser.User.value != 'TRAINER' && !'SYSTEM') {
           frmUser.textCustomer.style.backgroundColor = '#cccccc';
           frmUser.textCustomer.disabled = true;
           frmUser.textSiteCode.style.backgroundColor = '#cccccc';
           frmUser.textSiteCode.disabled = true;
           frmUser.option.disabled = true;
           frmUser.radioadd.disabled = true;
           frmUser.radiodelete.disabled = true;
           }
        });
```

this got it working